# Django поиск в Postgres

Tags: python, django, postgresql, search

Есть проблема c поиском в Django при миграции выдает ошибку.
На новой базе подключаю `CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;`,
потом последовательно

```
manage.py migrate
manage.py createsuperuser
manage.py makemigrations blog
manage.py migrate blog
```

и получаю ошибку

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ОШИБКА:  для типа данных character varying не определён класс операторов по умолчанию для метода доступа "gin"
HINT:  Вы должны указать класс операторов для индекса или определить класс операторов по умолчанию для этого типа данных.
```

На тестовой базе все работает но в чем причина понять не могу.
Как это исправить?

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
autor = models.ForeignKey(
    settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
title = models.CharField(max_length=120,
                         verbose_name='Title')  
slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, verbose_name='URL')
description = models.TextField(default='Description')
keywords = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='Keywords')
tags = models.ManyToManyField(TagsModel, blank=True, related_name='Tags')
img = models.ImageField(upload_to='blog/%Y/%m/%d/',
                        blank=True,
                        verbose_name='Images')
content = HTMLField()
visible = models.BooleanField(default=1)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,
                               auto_now_add=False,
                               verbose_name='Updated')  
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False,
                                 auto_now_add=True,
                                 verbose_name='Create')  

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return "/%s/" % (self.id)

class Meta:
    indexes = [GinIndex(fields=["title"])]
    ordering = ["-id", "-timestamp"]
    verbose_name = 'Post'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Posts'
```

view.py

```
class Search(ListView):
model = Post
paginate_by = 2
template_name = 'blog/partial/search.html'

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = super(Search, self).get_queryset()
    q = self.request.GET.get("q")
    if q:
        vector = SearchVector('title',
                              'content',
                              raw=True,
                              fields=('title'))
        vector_trgm = TrigramSimilarity(
            'title', q, raw=True, fields=('title')) + TrigramSimilarity(
                'content', q, raw=True, fields=('content'))
        a = queryset.annotate(search=vector).order_by('title').filter(
            search=q) or queryset.annotate(similarity=vector_trgm).filter(
                similarity__gt=0.1).order_by('title')
        if not a:  # Если НЕ найдено
            return ["Not found!"]
        else:  # если НАЙДЕНО
            return a
    elif not q:  # Если ПУСТОЙ запрос
        return ["Empty search string."]

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['q'] = self.request.GET.get('q', 2)
    return context
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не умею django. Зато я умею postgresql.

Как указано в документации к [`pg_trgm`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html#id-1.11.7.40.7), для использования этого расширения вы должны создавать индексы с явным указанием соответствующего operator class

```
CREATE INDEX trgm_idx ON test_trgm USING GIN (t gin_trgm_ops);
```

Ошибка вида:

> ОШИБКА:  для типа данных character varying не определён класс операторов по умолчанию для метода доступа "gin"
>   HINT:  Вы должны указать класс операторов для индекса или определить класс операторов по умолчанию для этого типа данных.

Однозначно сообщает о том, что operator class в запросе создания индекса указан не был. На тестовой базе у вас может сложиться впечатление что что-то работает по разным причинам. К примеру, потому, что у вас установлен `btree_gin` extension, который предоставляет operator class по-умолчанию для gin индексов по текстовым полям. Излишне добавлять, что к триграммному поиску это может не иметь никакого отношения.

Поиск мне говорит, что django необходимо [отдельно обучать](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44820345/10983392) добавлять operator class.

Comment: Благодарю за объяснения.